# Aggregate text based on clusters of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame as such:

> ```
>                                                 text  is_from_me
> 0                              Happy birthday bud!!!           1
> 1                                        Thanks man!           0
> 2  Definitely would've come back had I thought ab...           1
> 3                                         Your good            0
> 4                                          Okay haha           1
> 5                                    Have a good one           1
> 6                   Yea you too. What are you up to?           0
> 7                      No hw like I'm doing all day            1
> 8                                        Just got up           1
> 9     Same here. I went to the football game last...           0
> 10                  I think I saw that in your story           1
> 11                                               Win?          1
> 12                               Lost in last second           0
> 13                                     Aw, that sucks          1
> 14                      Means it was a good game tho?          1
> 15  Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard li...          0
> 16                                               Dang          1
> ```

I'm trying to produce the following:

> ```
>                                                input    output
> 0                              Happy birthday bud!!!    Thanks man!  
> 2                                        Thanks man!    Definitely would've come back had I thought ab...
> 3  Definitely would've come back had I thought ab...    Your good
> 4                                          Your good    Okay haha\nHave a good one
> 6                         Okay haha\nHave a good one    Yea you too. What are you up to?
> 7                   Yea you too. What are you up to?    No hw like I'm doing all day\nJust got up
> 9          No hw like I'm doing all day\nJust got up    Same here. I went to the football game last...
> 10    Same here. I went to the football game last...    I think I saw that in your story\nWin?
> 12            I think I saw that in your story\nWin?    Lost in last second
> 13                               Lost in last second    Aw, that sucks\nMeans it was a good game tho?
> 15     Aw, that sucks\nMeans it was a good game tho?    Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard li...
> 16 Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard li...    Dang
> ```

I can accomplish something close with this code:

```
pd.concat([df['text'].reset_index(drop=True), df['text'].shift(-1).reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

However, this doesn't combine the text based on `is_from_me` where the text for the group was combined with a newline character separating the original strings.  This is a simplistic example, there could be many more than 2 rows that would be grouped into one row.

I've tried coming up with a simple way to define this grouping, but all I can manage is a convoluted for loop that sorta does the job in a hacky way.  Is there an aggregation function I could write that would accomplish this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
input_ = df.groupby((df.is_from_me != df.is_from_me.shift()).cumsum())['text'].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x))
output = input_.shift(-1)
pd.concat([input_, output], axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    text    text
is_from_me      
1   Happy birthday bud!!!   Thanks man!
2   Thanks man! Definitely would've come back had I thought ab...
3   Definitely would've come back had I thought ab...   Your good
4   Your good   Okay haha\nHave a good one
5   Okay haha\nHave a good one  Yea you too. What are you up to?
6   Yea you too. What are you up to?    No hw like I'm doing all day\nJust got up
7   No hw like I'm doing all day\nJust got up   Same here. I went to the football game last...
8   Same here. I went to the football game last...  I think I saw that in your story\nWin?
9   I think I saw that in your story\nWin?  Lost in last second
10  Lost in last second Aw. that sucks\nMeans it was a good game tho?
11  Aw. that sucks\nMeans it was a good game tho?   Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard li...
12  Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard li...   Dang
13  Dang    NaN
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the clustering logic I described in the question.

Comment: Yup, I'm comparing against the other answer for speed, need some time to run tests

Answer (score 1):

You can use`pd.groupby`. Output looks ugly but it should be what you need

```
a = df.groupby([df.is_from_me.diff().ne(0).cumsum()]).agg(lambda x: tuple(x))
a['output'] = a['text']
a['input'] = a.shift()['text']
```

output

```
             input  \
is_from_me                                                      
1                                                         NaN   
2                                    (Happy birthday bud!!!,)   
3                                              (Thanks man!,)   
4           (Definitely would've come back had I thought a...   
5                                                (Your good,)   
6                                (Okay haha, Have a good one)   
7                         (Yea you too. What are you up to?,)   
8                 (No hw like I'm doing all day, Just got up)   
9           (Same here. I went to the football game last...,)   
10                   (I think I saw that in your story, Win?)   
11                                     (Lost in last second,)   
12            (Aw, that sucks, Means it was a good game tho?)   
13          (Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard l...   

                                                       output  
is_from_me                                                     
1                                    (Happy birthday bud!!!,)  
2                                              (Thanks man!,)  
3           (Definitely would've come back had I thought a...  
4                                                (Your good,)  
5                                (Okay haha, Have a good one)  
6                         (Yea you too. What are you up to?,)  
7                 (No hw like I'm doing all day, Just got up)  
8           (Same here. I went to the football game last...,)  
9                    (I think I saw that in your story, Win?)  
10                                     (Lost in last second,)  
11            (Aw, that sucks, Means it was a good game tho?)  
12          (Really good game. They were on the 1/2 yard l...  
13                                                    (Dang,)
```

Comment: Why use a tuple instead of a `'\n'.join(x)`?

Comment: just a style preference,  your approach works too :)